# Sharepoint ribbon is not working in windows 10

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Sharepoint ribbon is not working in windows 10...but ribbon is enable in all other windows version below 10..what will be the reason...any one guide me..

Comment: You might not have permissions for the ribbon. Try to check with admin account

Comment: thanks for your reply..but ribbon is not enabled in windows 10(not displayed)...but its enable in windows 7..

Comment: Is it visible in Win 7 for same user you are trying in win 10 ?

Comment: yes..for same user its not visible in windows 10..is anything to do with browser settings?

Answer (score 0):

Below are 2 possibilities - 
1. This happen when you are not using original windows 10.
2. If you are using SharePoint online  - you can usually bring back the ribbon if you click Return to Classic SharePoint at the bottom of the Quick Launch bar on the left of your screen. To exit Classic SharePoint, close all browser windows, and then log back into Office 365. If you don't see the classic SharePoint option, check with your administrator or IT dept, as they may have disabled it. 
Ref - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/why-sharepoint-ribbon-buttons-are-unavailable-48b0939a-2efb-4e79-b5e8-b2c4cb5d04ca